# Fitting multiple data with model and NDSolve with different initial conditions, and other shared parameters

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, variable-definitions, modeling

I know that there are already questions about fitting multiple datasets and about NDSolve and about shared and non shared parameters, but I tried to apply them and some things are still not clear.

Here is my equation :

```
l = 10^(-5)
k = 1/l
chic = 0.5
T = 100

eq = {R'[t] == -a[t]*R[t] + b[t], 
  b'[t] == beta/2*(Tanh[(chi[t] - chic)*k] - 1), 
  a'[t] == -alpha/2*(Tanh[(chi[t] - chic)*k] - 1), 
  chi'[t] == -kappa*R[t]*(chi[t] - 2*chic), a[0] == a0, b[0] == b0, 
  R[0] == R0, chi[0] == 0}
```

I want to fit with regards to the variables : $alpha, beta, kappa, a0, b0$ as shared parameters and $R0$ as non shared parameter, meaning it would be different fr each one.

The joined data is given as an appendix just afterwards.

The non-joined data (meaning the 5 data-sets separately) looks like that :

[image]

So I tried to change $R0$ as a variable, and I got inspired by the answer of @JimB in [Finding NonlinearModelFit of multiple data sets with the same parameters and in two dimensions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113234/finding-nonlinearmodelfit-of-multiple-data-sets-with-the-same-parameters-and-in) :

```
model[alpha_?NumberQ, beta_?NumberQ, kappa_?NumberQ, a0_?NumberQ, 
  b0_?NumberQ] :=  (model[alpha, beta, kappa, a0, b0] = 
   Module[{R, chi, b, a, t, R0}, 
    First[R /. 
      NDSolve[{D[R[t, R0], t] == -a[t, R0]*R[t, R0] + 
          b[t, R0], 
        D[b[t, R0], t] == beta/2*(Tanh[(chi[t, R0] - chic)*k] - 1), 
        D[a[t, R0], t] == -alpha/2*(Tanh[(chi[t, R0] - chic)*k] - 1), 
        D[chi[t, R0], t] == -kappa*(chi[t, R0] - 2*chic), 
        a[0, R0] == a0, b[0, R0] == b0, R[0, R0] == R0, chi[0,R0] == 0}, {R, b, 
        a, chi}, {t, 0, T}, {R0, 0, 300}]]]);
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   {model[alpha, beta, kappa, a0, b0][t, 
    R0], alpha >= 0, beta >= 0, kappa >= 0, a0 >= 0, b0 >= 0}, {{alpha, 0.1}, { beta, 0.1}, { kappa, 0.05}, {a0, 0.01}, {b0,
      3}}, {t, R0}];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

The parameters are believed to be around :

```
alpha = 0.1
beta= 0.1
kappa = 0.05
a0 = 0.01
b0 = 3
```

But it didn't work... :

> NonlinearModelFit::nrnum: The function value `1/2 ((-22.6124+R$3721[3.,22.])^2+(-119.51+R$3721[3.,119.])^2+(-24.738+R$3721[6.,22.])^2+(-60.1536+R$3721[6.,60.])^2+(-126.123+R$3721[6.,119.])^2+(-16.8895+R$3721[9.,17.])^2+(-25.4959+R$3721[9.,22.])^2+(-57.9807+R$3721[9.,60.])^2+(-110.446+R$3721[9.,119.])^2+(-17.3404+R$3721[12.,17.])^2+(-26.1946+R$3721[12.,22.])^2+(-60.9089+R$3721[12.,60.])^2+(-110.332+R$3721[12.,119.])^2+<<25>>+(-200.187+R$3721[27.,185.])^2+(-20.6519+R$3721[30.,17.])^2+(-34.5678+R$3721[30.,22.])^2+(-68.705+R$3721[30.,60.])^2+(-111.198+R$3721[30.,119.])^2+(-199.25+R$3721[30.,185.])^2+(-19.4591+R$3721[33.,17.])^2+(-35.9263+R$3721[33.,22.])^2+(-68.2107+R$3721[33.,60.])^2+(-109.903+R$3721[33.,119.])^2+(-198.411+R$3721[33.,185.])^2+(-20.6855+R$3721[36.,17.])^2+<<819>>)` is not a real number at `{alpha,beta,kappa,a0,b0} = {0.1,0.1,0.05,0.01,3.}`.

I assume there is an issue with $R0$, but I don't get where.

How could I proceed ?

Also, I don't know how I could fix a priori the initial conditions for each fit in order to extract only the shared parameters.

**DATA**

MathematicaStackExchange doesn't give the possibility to enter to much characters. I can give only the joined data.

**1. joined data with R0 as a variable**

Here is the joined data.

```
data={{9., 17., 16.8895}, {12., 17., 17.3404}, {15., 17., 17.1633}, {18., 
  17., 19.3417}, {21., 17., 17.9899}, {24., 17., 19.9677}, {27., 17., 
  19.4362}, {30., 17., 20.6519}, {33., 17., 19.4591}, {36., 17., 
  20.6855}, {39., 17., 20.1952}, {42., 17., 21.9949}, {45., 17., 
  21.0234}, {48., 17., 22.7408}, {51., 17., 22.3908}, {54., 17., 
  25.0918}, {57., 17., 23.5989}, {60., 17., 26.0703}, {63., 17., 
  24.5605}, {66., 17., 27.2539}, {69., 17., 26.1619}, {72., 17., 
  28.4762}, {75., 17., 27.5854}, {78., 17., 29.8393}, {81., 17., 
  28.3553}, {84., 17., 30.3221}, {87., 17., 29.675}, {90., 17., 
  31.5653}, {93., 17., 30.5337}, {96., 17., 33.3734}, {99., 17., 
  31.6876}, {102., 17., 34.1503}, {105., 17., 33.3065}, {108., 17., 
  35.3291}, {111., 17., 33.9209}, {114., 17., 36.773}, {117., 17., 
  35.4094}, {120., 17., 41.5902}, {123., 17., 36.1305}, {126., 17., 
  37.971}, {129., 17., 36.402}, {132., 17., 39.1158}, {135., 17., 
  38.0177}, {138., 17., 40.8558}, {141., 17., 39.6065}, {144., 17., 
  40.9749}, {147., 17., 39.8896}, {150., 17., 41.8237}, {153., 17., 
  40.5802}, {156., 17., 42.3858}, {159., 17., 40.6619}, {162., 17., 
  44.4442}, {165., 17., 45.4162}, {168., 17., 46.1884}, {171., 17., 
  44.6008}, {174., 17., 47.1647}, {177., 17., 45.3808}, {180., 17., 
  46.5859}, {183., 17., 45.3035}, {186., 17., 47.6604}, {189., 17., 
  46.6771}, {192., 17., 45.9242}, {195., 17., 46.767}, {198., 17., 
  44.6899}, {201., 17., 46.6628}, {204., 17., 46.1571}, {207., 17., 
  46.5555}, {210., 17., 44.835}, {213., 17., 45.1423}, {216., 17., 
  45.1954}, {219., 17., 45.309}, {222., 17., 47.7791}, {225., 17., 
  46.7777}, {228., 17., 48.135}, {231., 17., 45.6493}, {234., 17., 
  45.8933}, {237., 17., 46.1803}, {240., 17., 46.7285}, {243., 17., 
  46.8063}, {246., 17., 47.1679}, {249., 17., 46.8787}, {252., 17., 
  47.2715}, {255., 17., 47.5362}, {258., 17., 48.9234}, {261., 17., 
  47.5456}, {264., 17., 53.5554}, {267., 17., 52.5704}, {270., 17., 
  49.6049}, {273., 17., 49.1189}, {276., 17., 48.9498}, {279., 17., 
  49.6024}, {282., 17., 49.7491}, {285., 17., 53.1681}, {288., 17., 
  51.7124}, {291., 17., 50.8069}, {294., 17., 50.0237}, {297., 17., 
  50.5922}, {300., 17., 50.6518}, {303., 17., 50.8827}, {306., 17., 
  51.2245}, {309., 17., 51.0911}, {312., 17., 52.3379}, {315., 17., 
  52.5112}, {318., 17., 53.9182}, {321., 17., 53.7082}, {324., 17., 
  54.9239}, {327., 17., 53.7369}, {330., 17., 51.7204}, {333., 17., 
  55.993}, {336., 17., 56.8489}, {339., 17., 53.3037}, {342., 17., 
  52.0201}, {345., 17., 52.6267}, {348., 17., 52.5615}, {351., 17., 
  55.4133}, {354., 17., 55.5549}, {357., 17., 52.2672}, {360., 17., 
  54.2202}, {363., 17., 50.3245}, {366., 17., 54.0435}, {369., 17., 
  51.0724}, {372., 17., 51.2091}, {375., 17., 51.6602}, {378., 17., 
  51.3684}, {381., 17., 51.5346}, {384., 17., 51.9204}, {387., 17., 
  52.3952}, {390., 17., 52.9114}, {393., 17., 54.3833}, {396., 17., 
  55.1898}, {399., 17., 51.3853}, {402., 17., 55.048}, {405., 17., 
  50.8574}, {408., 17., 51.9619}, {411., 17., 52.5775}, {414., 17., 
  52.5676}, {417., 17., 51.0891}, {420., 17., 54.3895}, {423., 17., 
  54.7591}, {426., 17., 53.9934}, {429., 17., 53.8877}, {435., 17., 
  55.4067}, {441., 17., 56.0656}, {447., 17., 57.4607}, {453., 17., 
  51.6628}, {456., 17., 54.3568}, {459., 17., 57.6827}, {465., 17., 
  54.8474}, {468., 17., 51.0797}, {471., 17., 53.1862}, {474., 17., 
  53.3921}, {477., 17., 54.468}, {480., 17., 54.1083}, {483., 17., 
  50.7948}, {486., 17., 53.3431}, {489., 17., 48.8646}, {492., 17., 
  53.3906}, {495., 17., 51.6016}, {498., 17., 54.1742}, {501., 17., 
  54.6549}, {504., 17., 50.0598}, {507., 17., 53.849}, {510., 17., 
  52.6431}, {513., 17., 54.3103}, {516., 17., 50.5004}, {519., 17., 
  50.8213}, {522., 17., 50.8512}, {525., 17., 52.4319}, {528., 17., 
  55.2716}, {3., 22., 22.6124}, {6., 22., 24.738}, {9., 22., 
  25.4959}, {12., 22., 26.1946}, {15., 22., 27.6091}, {18., 22., 
  29.1024}, {21., 22., 30.6462}, {24., 22., 32.9126}, {27., 22., 
  34.1471}, {30., 22., 34.5678}, {33., 22., 35.9263}, {36., 22., 
  37.4284}, {39., 22., 38.5027}, {42., 22., 39.5611}, {45., 22., 
  40.743}, {48., 22., 41.9482}, {51., 22., 42.7558}, {54., 22., 
  43.5064}, {57., 22., 44.43}, {60., 22., 45.7449}, {63., 22., 
  47.0524}, {66., 22., 48.0848}, {69., 22., 48.8836}, {72., 22., 
  49.6807}, {75., 22., 50.6801}, {78., 22., 51.6959}, {81., 22., 
  52.6475}, {84., 22., 53.5902}, {87., 22., 54.4008}, {90., 22., 
  54.774}, {93., 22., 55.6085}, {96., 22., 56.3299}, {99., 22., 
  56.4428}, {102., 22., 56.7936}, {105., 22., 57.4926}, {108., 22., 
  58.2406}, {111., 22., 59.1169}, {114., 22., 59.5766}, {117., 22., 
  59.7909}, {120., 22., 61.6917}, {123., 22., 62.4342}, {126., 22., 
  61.5979}, {129., 22., 61.8203}, {132., 22., 62.5629}, {135., 22., 
  63.4556}, {138., 22., 63.688}, {141., 22., 63.9159}, {144., 22., 
  63.9802}, {147., 22., 64.1833}, {150., 22., 64.3304}, {153., 22., 
  64.3847}, {156., 22., 64.6173}, {159., 22., 64.9009}, {162., 22., 
  65.1622}, {165., 22., 65.4684}, {168., 22., 65.5182}, {171., 22., 
  66.1171}, {174., 22., 66.4103}, {177., 22., 66.2592}, {180., 22., 
  66.185}, {183., 22., 65.8147}, {186., 22., 65.733}, {189., 22., 
  65.6618}, {192., 22., 64.7882}, {195., 22., 64.8274}, {198., 22., 
  64.9444}, {201., 22., 63.1305}, {204., 22., 62.3995}, {207., 22., 
  63.0431}, {210., 22., 62.2181}, {213., 22., 62.5286}, {216., 22., 
  62.1711}, {219., 22., 60.8353}, {222., 22., 60.7586}, {225., 22., 
  60.7004}, {228., 22., 59.5638}, {231., 22., 59.1517}, {234., 22., 
  58.9346}, {237., 22., 59.0493}, {240., 22., 59.5229}, {243., 22., 
  58.0876}, {246., 22., 56.247}, {249., 22., 56.173}, {252., 22., 
  56.1419}, {255., 22., 55.2417}, {258., 22., 56.2456}, {261., 22., 
  57.9169}, {264., 22., 60.728}, {267., 22., 63.6912}, {270., 22., 
  61.9647}, {273., 22., 57.0852}, {276., 22., 54.2803}, {279., 22., 
  55.3487}, {282., 22., 58.0208}, {285., 22., 60.8749}, {288., 22., 
  61.029}, {291., 22., 59.3053}, {294., 22., 56.7078}, {297., 22., 
  53.8873}, {300., 22., 55.2545}, {303., 22., 56.5482}, {306., 22., 
  56.0664}, {309., 22., 55.2537}, {312., 22., 55.3196}, {315., 22., 
  55.8909}, {318., 22., 55.6318}, {321., 22., 56.213}, {324., 22., 
  55.4207}, {327., 22., 54.2877}, {330., 22., 55.1178}, {333., 22., 
  51.193}, {336., 22., 48.5713}, {339., 22., 49.5028}, {342., 22., 
  49.4166}, {345., 22., 50.0304}, {348., 22., 50.9326}, {351., 22., 
  52.014}, {354., 22., 50.2956}, {357., 22., 49.8529}, {360., 22., 
  50.8205}, {363., 22., 51.376}, {366., 22., 50.6679}, {369., 22., 
  51.6815}, {372., 22., 53.5813}, {375., 22., 53.7359}, {378., 22., 
  54.6252}, {381., 22., 55.2786}, {384., 22., 53.4308}, {387., 22., 
  54.5401}, {390., 22., 57.9795}, {393., 22., 55.2026}, {396., 22., 
  55.386}, {399., 22., 59.8766}, {402., 22., 58.1028}, {405., 22., 
  57.129}, {408., 22., 56.9853}, {411., 22., 57.2221}, {414., 22., 
  56.9648}, {417., 22., 55.586}, {420., 22., 56.7903}, {423., 22., 
  56.2825}, {426., 22., 53.8012}, {429., 22., 52.6652}, {432., 22., 
  54.2455}, {435., 22., 56.3002}, {438., 22., 56.2343}, {441., 22., 
  56.7575}, {444., 22., 56.7977}, {447., 22., 56.3049}, {450., 22., 
  54.6538}, {453., 22., 52.5136}, {456., 22., 52.3433}, {459., 22., 
  52.828}, {462., 22., 54.0433}, {465., 22., 51.5131}, {468., 22., 
  50.4781}, {471., 22., 52.6831}, {474., 22., 52.4475}, {477., 22., 
  52.6825}, {480., 22., 52.5579}, {483., 22., 52.8213}, {486., 22., 
  53.6997}, {489., 22., 53.3714}, {492., 22., 52.3218}, {495., 22., 
  52.3176}, {498., 22., 53.8036}, {501., 22., 53.7502}, {504., 22., 
  55.6969}, {507., 22., 56.1864}, {510., 22., 52.9824}, {513., 22., 
  55.2477}, {516., 22., 54.727}, {519., 22., 54.0447}, {522., 22., 
  56.1034}, {525., 22., 53.0694}, {528., 22., 51.3001}, {6., 60., 
  60.1536}, {9., 60., 57.9807}, {12., 60., 60.9089}, {15., 60., 
  59.4291}, {18., 60., 61.3227}, {21., 60., 61.8788}, {24., 60., 
  67.2192}, {27., 60., 66.2767}, {30., 60., 68.705}, {33., 60., 
  68.2107}, {36., 60., 70.8731}, {39., 60., 68.7269}, {42., 60., 
  73.2306}, {45., 60., 72.3068}, {48., 60., 74.8006}, {51., 60., 
  72.1975}, {54., 60., 76.577}, {57., 60., 75.5894}, {60., 60., 
  76.342}, {63., 60., 75.5134}, {66., 60., 77.47}, {69., 60., 
  76.6854}, {72., 60., 78.7422}, {75., 60., 78.6074}, {78., 60., 
  81.0158}, {81., 60., 82.8521}, {84., 60., 85.1395}, {87., 60., 
  85.211}, {90., 60., 84.5157}, {93., 60., 83.622}, {96., 60., 
  88.1703}, {99., 60., 85.6195}, {102., 60., 86.8345}, {105., 60., 
  86.5568}, {108., 60., 87.5942}, {111., 60., 88.3053}, {114., 60., 
  88.3475}, {117., 60., 89.3993}, {120., 60., 91.7091}, {123., 60., 
  89.7268}, {126., 60., 90.6704}, {129., 60., 89.7999}, {132., 60., 
  90.369}, {135., 60., 88.7787}, {138., 60., 90.3022}, {141., 60., 
  89.8267}, {144., 60., 91.2241}, {147., 60., 91.2859}, {150., 60., 
  92.992}, {153., 60., 91.0079}, {156., 60., 93.0784}, {159., 60., 
  90.8868}, {162., 60., 92.7426}, {165., 60., 92.757}, {168., 60., 
  94.4202}, {171., 60., 92.2914}, {174., 60., 90.3876}, {177., 60., 
  89.3376}, {180., 60., 89.814}, {183., 60., 88.9134}, {186., 60., 
  89.7058}, {189., 60., 91.642}, {192., 60., 90.3205}, {195., 60., 
  87.8566}, {198., 60., 87.6065}, {201., 60., 87.0403}, {204., 60., 
  87.3344}, {207., 60., 87.2313}, {210., 60., 87.3705}, {213., 60., 
  86.9135}, {216., 60., 87.2684}, {219., 60., 87.2989}, {222., 60., 
  85.4766}, {225., 60., 85.3534}, {228., 60., 86.535}, {231., 60., 
  86.1929}, {234., 60., 86.089}, {237., 60., 85.9466}, {240., 60., 
  85.1389}, {243., 60., 85.0242}, {246., 60., 84.4313}, {249., 60., 
  83.7604}, {252., 60., 81.9419}, {255., 60., 83.773}, {258., 60., 
  82.7046}, {261., 60., 84.7331}, {264., 60., 86.0393}, {267., 60., 
  84.7472}, {270., 60., 79.1677}, {273., 60., 80.9426}, {276., 60., 
  79.9624}, {279., 60., 75.5272}, {282., 60., 79.3103}, {285., 60., 
  80.8015}, {288., 60., 81.3927}, {291., 60., 80.1678}, {294., 60., 
  80.268}, {297., 60., 79.9067}, {300., 60., 76.9766}, {303., 60., 
  81.8132}, {306., 60., 73.6449}, {309., 60., 76.4059}, {312., 60., 
  76.4056}, {315., 60., 81.7311}, {318., 60., 80.8468}, {321., 60., 
  80.958}, {324., 60., 86.9248}, {327., 60., 78.3434}, {330., 60., 
  74.8752}, {333., 60., 78.0912}, {336., 60., 81.5165}, {339., 60., 
  72.7919}, {342., 60., 74.2966}, {345., 60., 79.2233}, {348., 60., 
  81.9791}, {351., 60., 74.3276}, {354., 60., 85.1221}, {357., 60., 
  78.6944}, {360., 60., 75.8183}, {363., 60., 75.6696}, {366., 60., 
  75.9147}, {369., 60., 76.3326}, {372., 60., 80.0048}, {375., 60., 
  79.8311}, {378., 60., 79.0427}, {381., 60., 81.8084}, {384., 60., 
  73.5742}, {387., 60., 84.2291}, {390., 60., 84.9122}, {393., 60., 
  82.6657}, {396., 60., 78.2888}, {399., 60., 90.0235}, {402., 60., 
  83.3667}, {405., 60., 81.7737}, {408., 60., 81.19}, {411., 60., 
  82.3131}, {414., 60., 79.8072}, {417., 60., 74.4822}, {420., 60., 
  75.6291}, {423., 60., 82.2655}, {426., 60., 73.704}, {429., 60., 
  81.4184}, {432., 60., 72.1127}, {435., 60., 74.7053}, {438., 60., 
  79.4664}, {441., 60., 86.4491}, {444., 60., 79.5096}, {447., 60., 
  77.1761}, {450., 60., 83.082}, {453., 60., 80.3418}, {456., 60., 
  85.3873}, {459., 60., 85.7409}, {462., 60., 73.3735}, {465., 60., 
  72.2276}, {468., 60., 82.7752}, {471., 60., 71.6917}, {474., 60., 
  78.5233}, {477., 60., 82.4042}, {480., 60., 83.8073}, {483., 60., 
  91.5845}, {486., 60., 82.8906}, {489., 60., 87.3935}, {492., 60., 
  89.9856}, {495., 60., 74.1819}, {498., 60., 77.5752}, {501., 60., 
  82.6796}, {504., 60., 79.2659}, {507., 60., 81.5865}, {510., 60., 
  82.709}, {513., 60., 88.4083}, {516., 60., 81.7317}, {519., 60., 
  76.2638}, {522., 60., 86.2863}, {525., 60., 93.2163}, {528., 60., 
  82.6943}, {3., 119., 119.51}, {6., 119., 126.123}, {9., 119., 
  110.446}, {12., 119., 110.332}, {15., 119., 110.478}, {18., 119., 
  111.335}, {21., 119., 109.536}, {24., 119., 111.901}, {27., 119., 
  110.46}, {30., 119., 111.198}, {33., 119., 109.903}, {36., 119., 
  110.72}, {39., 119., 109.635}, {42., 119., 110.643}, {45., 119., 
  109.528}, {48., 119., 110.348}, {51., 119., 110.117}, {54., 119., 
  109.117}, {57., 119., 108.536}, {60., 119., 108.615}, {63., 119., 
  109.495}, {66., 119., 111.304}, {69., 119., 111.139}, {72., 119., 
  114.285}, {75., 119., 113.627}, {78., 119., 114.77}, {81., 119., 
  114.544}, {84., 119., 115.304}, {87., 119., 114.895}, {90., 119., 
  115.859}, {93., 119., 114.357}, {96., 119., 115.038}, {99., 119., 
  114.305}, {102., 119., 115.09}, {105., 119., 114.815}, {108., 119., 
  113.203}, {111., 119., 113.46}, {114., 119., 114.573}, {117., 119., 
  113.339}, {120., 119., 114.354}, {123., 119., 112.285}, {126., 119.,
   112.695}, {129., 119., 112.032}, {132., 119., 112.253}, {135., 
  119., 108.945}, {138., 119., 109.271}, {141., 119., 108.654}, {144.,
   119., 104.336}, {147., 119., 103.609}, {150., 119., 
  105.778}, {153., 119., 105.077}, {156., 119., 104.868}, {159., 119.,
   103.945}, {162., 119., 104.039}, {165., 119., 101.727}, {168., 
  119., 97.6562}, {171., 119., 99.6703}, {174., 119., 96.6503}, {177.,
   119., 98.3032}, {180., 119., 98.8859}, {183., 119., 
  97.9825}, {186., 119., 94.8383}, {189., 119., 93.4101}, {192., 119.,
   88.9132}, {195., 119., 91.7409}, {198., 119., 93.2425}, {201., 
  119., 86.1268}, {204., 119., 84.9263}, {207., 119., 86.3445}, {210.,
   119., 84.4667}, {213., 119., 85.9353}, {216., 119., 
  85.7998}, {219., 119., 85.2672}, {222., 119., 86.3356}, {225., 119.,
   86.7423}, {228., 119., 86.1353}, {231., 119., 84.8631}, {234., 
  119., 84.7305}, {237., 119., 83.385}, {240., 119., 87.5174}, {243., 
  119., 83.3014}, {246., 119., 86.9219}, {249., 119., 78.3219}, {252.,
   119., 78.9197}, {255., 119., 74.785}, {258., 119., 67.8261}, {261.,
   119., 75.8036}, {264., 119., 86.2339}, {267., 119., 
  87.3689}, {270., 119., 88.1322}, {273., 119., 86.1332}, {276., 119.,
   89.9111}, {279., 119., 90.5619}, {282., 119., 88.4012}, {285., 
  119., 85.5809}, {288., 119., 76.692}, {291., 119., 80.0753}, {294., 
  119., 90.1118}, {297., 119., 91.8565}, {300., 119., 85.0882}, {303.,
   119., 89.1269}, {306., 119., 96.8869}, {309., 119., 
  75.4618}, {312., 119., 96.3013}, {315., 119., 89.4435}, {318., 119.,
   103.21}, {321., 119., 94.6233}, {324., 119., 102.48}, {327., 119., 
  96.7664}, {330., 119., 84.2408}, {333., 119., 97.3822}, {336., 119.,
   74.2619}, {339., 119., 87.2886}, {342., 119., 118.024}, {345., 
  119., 113.648}, {348., 119., 112.4}, {351., 119., 107.295}, {354., 
  119., 111.618}, {357., 119., 112.181}, {360., 119., 112.119}, {363.,
   119., 90.6252}, {366., 119., 106.837}, {369., 119., 
  99.7227}, {372., 119., 97.5255}, {375., 119., 108.211}, {378., 119.,
   117.211}, {381., 119., 97.9301}, {384., 119., 104.567}, {387., 
  119., 117.343}, {390., 119., 121.622}, {393., 119., 106.117}, {396.,
   119., 116.022}, {399., 119., 118.856}, {402., 119., 
  106.854}, {405., 119., 112.418}, {408., 119., 112.79}, {411., 119., 
  112.225}, {414., 119., 116.686}, {417., 119., 111.297}, {420., 119.,
   115.404}, {423., 119., 117.563}, {426., 119., 116.243}, {429., 
  119., 119.805}, {432., 119., 112.863}, {435., 119., 103.505}, {438.,
   119., 116.846}, {441., 119., 115.508}, {444., 119., 
  115.579}, {447., 119., 101.756}, {450., 119., 102.848}, {453., 119.,
   112.506}, {456., 119., 113.93}, {459., 119., 116.386}, {462., 119.,
   108.138}, {465., 119., 108.635}, {468., 119., 110.514}, {471., 
  119., 108.217}, {474., 119., 110.008}, {477., 119., 95.7788}, {480.,
   119., 92.8073}, {483., 119., 104.382}, {486., 119., 98.77}, {489., 
  119., 112.527}, {492., 119., 94.6092}, {495., 119., 89.2861}, {498.,
   119., 92.0002}, {501., 119., 98.7618}, {504., 119., 
  105.274}, {507., 119., 96.7057}, {510., 119., 93.5207}, {513., 119.,
   90.5992}, {516., 119., 87.1486}, {519., 119., 103.466}, {522., 
  119., 100.133}, {525., 119., 120.605}, {528., 119., 125.717}, {12., 
  185., 185.791}, {15., 185., 199.035}, {18., 185., 197.796}, {21., 
  185., 185.256}, {24., 185., 199.576}, {27., 185., 200.187}, {30., 
  185., 199.25}, {33., 185., 198.411}, {36., 185., 198.288}, {39., 
  185., 194.506}, {42., 185., 189.658}, {45., 185., 191.203}, {48., 
  185., 185.757}, {51., 185., 183.642}, {54., 185., 183.513}, {57., 
  185., 186.524}, {60., 185., 182.793}, {63., 185., 182.218}, {66., 
  185., 182.045}, {69., 185., 176.614}, {72., 185., 182.432}, {75., 
  185., 181.409}, {78., 185., 182.438}, {81., 185., 179.939}, {84., 
  185., 182.435}, {87., 185., 181.521}, {90., 185., 176.654}, {93., 
  185., 175.39}, {96., 185., 179.446}, {99., 185., 173.541}, {102., 
  185., 176.645}, {105., 185., 176.715}, {108., 185., 173.915}, {111.,
   185., 173.14}, {114., 185., 173.045}, {117., 185., 160.089}, {120.,
   185., 165.306}, {123., 185., 165.906}, {126., 185., 
  165.712}, {129., 185., 159.285}, {132., 185., 163.219}, {135., 185.,
   156.287}, {138., 185., 150.445}, {141., 185., 153.388}, {144., 
  185., 138.083}, {147., 185., 137.152}, {150., 185., 133.003}, {153.,
   185., 130.634}, {156., 185., 131.832}, {159., 185., 
  136.142}, {162., 185., 133.906}, {165., 185., 130.929}, {168., 185.,
   136.717}, {171., 185., 129.749}, {174., 185., 148.377}, {177., 
  185., 133.068}, {180., 185., 149.921}, {183., 185., 134.802}, {186.,
   185., 150.543}, {189., 185., 138.678}, {192., 185., 147.06}, {195.,
   185., 143.604}, {198., 185., 143.368}, {201., 185., 
  140.587}, {204., 185., 138.171}, {207., 185., 140.699}, {210., 185.,
   137.346}, {213., 185., 126.241}, {216., 185., 131.743}, {219., 
  185., 134.835}, {222., 185., 134.086}, {225., 185., 137.185}, {228.,
   185., 135.892}, {231., 185., 141.62}, {234., 185., 135.963}, {237.,
   185., 133.382}, {240., 185., 134.258}, {243., 185., 
  141.568}, {246., 185., 137.642}, {249., 185., 131.681}, {252., 185.,
   132.635}, {255., 185., 134.506}, {258., 185., 136.089}, {261., 
  185., 138.973}, {264., 185., 141.048}, {267., 185., 133.785}, {270.,
   185., 133.245}, {273., 185., 116.408}, {276., 185., 123.9}, {279., 
  185., 120.251}, {282., 185., 116.984}, {285., 185., 135.753}, {288.,
   185., 123.026}, {291., 185., 112.116}, {294., 185., 
  134.164}, {297., 185., 134.548}, {300., 185., 129.032}, {303., 185.,
   116.97}, {306., 185., 113.993}, {309., 185., 99.4695}, {312., 185.,
   97.4854}, {315., 185., 100.422}, {318., 185., 117.461}, {321., 
  185., 99.4758}, {324., 185., 106.366}, {327., 185., 108.271}, {330.,
   185., 104.738}, {333., 185., 117.487}, {336., 185., 
  101.704}, {339., 185., 101.32}, {342., 185., 112.97}, {345., 185., 
  96.6092}, {348., 185., 99.2531}, {351., 185., 120.19}, {354., 185., 
  124.284}, {357., 185., 130.082}, {360., 185., 121.699}, {363., 185.,
   108.539}, {366., 185., 103.98}, {369., 185., 100.293}, {372., 185.,
   94.7848}, {375., 185., 103.281}, {378., 185., 114.4}, {381., 185., 
  94.8752}, {384., 185., 101.51}, {387., 185., 104.285}, {390., 185., 
  107.424}, {393., 185., 112.506}, {396., 185., 104.061}, {399., 185.,
   113.713}, {402., 185., 136.378}, {405., 185., 134.92}, {408., 185.,
   139.111}, {411., 185., 143.397}, {414., 185., 139.998}, {417., 
  185., 137.19}, {420., 185., 143.812}, {423., 185., 133.346}, {426., 
  185., 141.8}, {429., 185., 136.171}, {432., 185., 137.842}, {435., 
  185., 147.509}, {438., 185., 140.488}, {441., 185., 142.855}, {444.,
   185., 151.992}, {447., 185., 145.348}, {450., 185., 
  138.757}, {453., 185., 135.964}, {456., 185., 140.381}, {459., 185.,
   143.697}, {462., 185., 136.854}, {465., 185., 129.477}, {468., 
  185., 138.181}, {471., 185., 142.726}, {474., 185., 143.633}, {477.,
   185., 133.913}, {480., 185., 157.635}, {483., 185., 
  147.941}, {486., 185., 142.015}, {489., 185., 130.545}, {492., 185.,
   141.941}, {495., 185., 142.863}, {498., 185., 135.462}, {501., 
  185., 139.637}, {504., 185., 128.002}, {507., 185., 140.211}, {510.,
   185., 140.209}, {513., 185., 132.36}, {516., 185., 141.088}, {519.,
   185., 142.756}, {522., 185., 152.256}, {525., 185., 
  164.725}, {528., 185., 153.737}}
```

Comment: Observe the output of the following code piece and think about the reason: `expr = x;
Module[{x}, {x, expr}]`

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for helping. Do you mean that x is going to be evaluated and expr is not going to be evaluated and that's why the output in your example is  {x$24532, x}  ?

Comment: I have to admit I do not understand the link between this and my issue.... Could you be a bit more explicit plz ?

Comment: No, this isn't that related to evaluation order. (Though it's not impossible to fix by tackling evaluation order. ) The main issue here is, 1. `Module` localizes variable by renaming it as `…$…`. (In the case above, `x` becomes `x$24532`); 2. When localizing, `Module` only _sees_ **explicit** variable i.e. the `x` _inside_ `expr` is not _noticed_ by `Module` so it's not localized and not renamed. And the same thing happens on your `R`.

Comment: Only those **explicit** `R`s are localized. You have `R`s _inside_ `eq`.

Comment: So I replaced `eq`  by an explicit formulation, and I entered `chi,a,b` into the local variables specification, but it's still not working.

Comment: Please show the specific code. Also, the `{R0, 0, 300}` in `NDSolve` only makes the code unnecessarily complicated, and you've missed the initial condition for `chi` in your code, and `D[chi[t, R0], t][t, R0]` is obviously wrong. As to the update, `alpha >= 0, 
        beta >= 0, kappa >= 0, a0 >= 0, b0 >= 0` doesn't make sense, please don't _guess_ the syntax, check the document of `NDSolve` carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94118/discussion-between-j-a-and-xzczd).

Comment: If I `ListPlot` your data I do not get your figure. In fact, `data` is a list of $3$-tuples, so I'm not sure how you expect to reconstruct the five graphs in your figure. Can you clarify how to obtain the figure from `data`? What is the exact code you use to generate it?

Comment: Are we supposed to fit the joined data or the non-joined data? If the latter, can you please post it?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I'm sorry but there would be too much characters, and the stackexchange doesn't allow it... The method I used used the joined data, with R0 as a variable.

Comment: @J.A You can (and arguably should) use `pastebin.com`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Another possible choice is to use the selected cell button of [SE uploader](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521/1871).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subject of parameter fitting comes up frequently on MSE.  Parameter fitting is a difficult subject and will depend on your data quality, your model, and your intial guesses.  I have been dabbling with StringTemplates as a potential way to encapsulate some of the basic parameter fitting work flow.

## Approach

- Use ParametricNDSolveValue to create the model.
- Use StringTemplates to handle lists of parameters and variables.
- Generate a Manipulate slider model to debug model and understand the effects of parameter changes.
- Transfer initial guesses from manipulate to perform a fit.

## Implementation

I commented the code so I hope it self explanatory.  First assign the constants and prep the data.

```
(* Evaluate data first *)
(* Constants *)
l = 10^(-5);
k = 1/l;
chic = 0.5;
T = 550;
(* Get unique R0s *)
R0s = Union@data[[All, 2]];
(* Subset Matching R0 and Delete 2nd Column *)
rdat = (Cases[data, {_, #, _}][[All, {1, 3}]] & /@ R0s);
```

Now, set up the equations and the Manipulate slider to view how the model behaves and try to improve initial parameters estimates.

```
(* Generate System of Differential Equations *)
e1 = R'[t] == -a[t]*R[t] + b[t];
e3 = b'[t] == beta/2*(Tanh[(chi[t] - chic)*k] - 1);
e2 = a'[t] == -alpha/2*(Tanh[(chi[t] - chic)*k] - 1);
e4 = chi'[t] == -kappa*R[t]*(chi[t] - 2*chic);
ics = {a[0] == a0, b[0] == b0, R[0] == R0, chi[0] == 0};
eqns = {e1, e2, e3, e4}~Join~ics;
(*Variables*)
vbles = {R, a, b, chi};
(*Parameters with target and desired ranges*)
mat = {
   {alpha, 0.1, 0.00025, 0.5},
   {beta, 0.1, 0.00025, 0.5},
   {kappa, 0.05, 0.0125, 0.1},
   {a0, 0.01, 0.00005, 0.1},
   {b0, 3, 1, 6},
   {R0, 17, 17, 185}
   };
(* reduce the matrix because R0 does not participate in parameter \
fits *)
rmat = mat[[1 ;; -2]];
(* Build Manipulate sliders *)
sfun =  StringRiffle[(StringTemplate[
         "{{`1`,`2`},`3`,`4`,Appearance\[Rule]\"Labeled\"}"] @@ #) & \
/@ #, ","] &;
sliders = sfun[rmat];
(* Extract Parameters from mat *)
parms = mat[[All, 1]];
rparms = rmat[[All, 1]];
(* Create String Representations of parms *)
sparms = StringRiffle[ToString[#] & /@ parms, ","];
rsparms = StringRiffle[ToString[#] & /@ rparms, ","];
(* Create patterns and string reps of parameters *)
pats = Pattern @@@ (#*_ & /@ parms);
spats = StringRiffle[ToString[#] & /@ pats, ","];
(* List Plot of the data *)
lp = Graphics[{Hue[#2/185], PointSize[0.01], Point[{#1, #3}]} & @@@ 
    data, Axes -> True];
(* ParametricNDSolveValue *)
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, vbles, {t, 0, T}, parms];
(*Create an appropriate model function to fit*)
modelstring = "(#[[1]])&";
(* Create some PlotLegends *)
pl = ",PlotLegends\[Rule]{" <> 
   StringRiffle["\"R0=" <> ToString[#] <> "\"" & /@ R0s, ","] <> "}";
(* Build the model expression *)
ToExpression[
 StringTemplate[
   "model[`pats`][t_]:=`ms`@Through[pfun[`params`][t],List]\
/;And@@NumericQ/@{`params`};"][<|"pats" -> spats, "params" -> sparms, 
   "ms" -> modelstring|>]]
(* Create slider model *)
globalstring = 
  StringTemplate["global={`params`};"][<|"params" -> rsparms|>];
mantemp = 
  "Manipulate[`g`\[IndentingNewLine]Show[lp,Plot[Evaluate@({model[\
alpha,beta,kappa,a0,b0,#][t]}&/@R0s),{t,0,T},PlotRange\[Rule]{0,200}`\
pl`],ImageSize->Large],`sliders`]";
ToExpression@
 StringTemplate[mantemp][<|"sliders" -> sliders, "params" -> rsparms, 
   "pl" -> pl, "g" -> globalstring|>]
(*Display global variable*)
Dynamic@global
```

[image: Manipulate Image]

Now set up to fit the funtions for each R0 value.

```
(* Grab The initial parameter guesses *)
initguess = MapThread[List, {rparms, First@Dynamic@global}];
(* Create a fit function to operate on different R0s *)
fitfn = FindFit[rdat[[#]], 
    model[alpha, beta, kappa, a0, b0, R0s[[#]]][t], initguess, t, 
    Method -> "Gradient"] &;
(* Perform Fits on R0s *)
fits = fitfn[#][[All, 2]] & /@ Range@Length@R0s;
(* Display Results *)
fits // MatrixForm
Mean@fits
```

[image: Parameter Estimates]

The data is noisy leading to some dodgy results for the high R0.  You can experiment with different fitting options, but you may need to improve your model and/or your data acquisition.

## Update to Fit per $R_0$ Data set

As requested, here is a way to fit per data set.  I also allowed $R_0$ to be fit using the column value as an initial guess.  In this case, each fitted row is plotted.  A word of caution, some fitting methods will run forever, so you may need to experiment.

```
(* Grab The initial parameter guesses from dynamic variable of slider \
*)
initguess = 
  MapThread[List, {parms, (First@Dynamic@global)~Join~{R0s[[#]]}}] &;
(* Create a fit function to operate on different R0s *)
fitfn = FindFit[rdat[[#]], model[alpha, beta, kappa, a0, b0, R0][t], 
    initguess[#], t, Method -> "Gradient", WorkingPrecision -> 10] &;
(* Perform Fits on R0s *)
(*fits = fitfn[#][[All,2]]&/@Range@Length@R0s;*)
fits = fitfn[#][[All, 2]] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
(* Display Results *)
fits // MatrixForm
mfit = Mean@fits
mat2 = rmat;
mat2[[All, 2]] = mfit[[1 ;; -2]];
Show[{lp, 
  Plot[Evaluate@((model @@ #)[t] & /@ fits), {t, 0, T}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 200}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"R0=17.", "R0=22.", "R0=60.", "R0=119.", 
     "R0=185."}]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Individual Fits]

Comment: Thanks this is a great job, and a very nice way to proceed. The only question I have is with regard to the fitting process. Is taking the mean the only way to proceed ? Meaning is there another way to gather the informations from the different data-sets ?

Comment: I added a plot of the fitted parameters for each row.